# Join two files lines in the same line with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have 2 files with the same number of lines and in the same order.

Example

Text 1:

```
1,MA,DC
2,NY,BC
3,CT,CD
```

Text 2

```
,PRO,123
,PRO,ABC
,GRO,XYZ
```

The output should be:

```
1,MA,DC,PRO,123
2,NY,BC,PRO,ABC
3,CT,CD,GRO,XYZ
```

So far I tried using the Join command and add-content but I'm getting with the second set at the bottom of the first set. I'm just trying to join lines into one line. 
I'm also thinking of creating datasets and loop but I thought that there may be an easier way like **cat** in Shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read both files into arrays and zip them in a regular for loop:

```
$File1 = Get-Content C:\path\to\file1.txt
$File2 = Get-Content C:\path\to\file2.txt

for($i = 0; $i -lt $File1.Count; $i++)
{
    ('{0}{1}' -f $File1[$i],$File2[$i]) |Add-Content C:\path\to\output.txt
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`cat` won't give you that either. Also I'm not quite sure what you mean by "join command".

Nevertheless, this is not too hard. Simply read both files, and concatenate the lines:

```
$a = Get-Content text1
$b = Get-Content text2

0..[Math]::Max($a.Length, $b.Length) | ForEach-Object {
  $a[$_] + $b[$_]
}
```

`Math.Max` simply ensures that the code still works regardless of whether both files have the same number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Get-Content in the default array-producing mode is extremely slow, and keeps the entire contents of files in memory, which won't gonna work with huge files. The other answers take 10 and 100 seconds on a 4MB log file with 100k lines.

Use .NET classes IO.StreamReader and IO.StreamWriter to join 4MB files in *100 milliseconds*
and 100MB files in 2 seconds instead of minutes/hours. However such excellent results are seen only in PS3.0 and newer, while PS2 uses much slower ancient runtime (still faster than Get-Content).

```
function Join-FileLines (
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -literal $_})] [string] $file1,
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -literal $_})] [string] $file2,
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -literal $_ -IsValid})] [string] $output
) {
    $a = New-Object IO.StreamReader $file1
    $b = New-Object IO.StreamReader $file2
    $c = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($output,
                                     $false, # don't append
                                     [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    while (!$a.EndOfStream -or !$b.EndOfStream) {
        $c.WriteLine($a.ReadLine() + $b.ReadLine())
    }
    $a.Close()
    $b.Close()
    $c.Close()
}
```

And a multi-file joiner:

```
function Join-FileLines(
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -literal $_})] [string[]] $files,
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -literal $_ -IsValid})] [string] $output
) {
    $streams = $files | ForEach { New-Object IO.StreamReader $_ }
    $streamOut = New-Object IO.StreamWriter ($output, $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    while ($true) {
        $anyLeft = $false
        ForEach ($s in $streams) {
            $anyLeft = $anyLeft -or !$s.EndOfStream
            $streamOut.Write($s.ReadLine())
        }
        if (!$anyLeft) { break }
        $streamOut.WriteLine()
    }
    ForEach ($s in $streams) { $s.Close() }
    $streamOut.Close()
}
```

Comment: Granted, slowness is an issue with the other approaches, but there was nothing in the question to suggest they have multi-GiB text files.

Comment: It's good to have examples of efficient processing now and then to show it's doable in Powershell.

Comment: Great to know. My current files are small but may be in the future they may get heavier. Thanks!